# Como funciona a interação entre as camadas em C# e qual a função de cada uma?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Supondo um projeto com essas camadas: `DAL`, `Controller`, `Negocio`, `Model` e `View`

Estou tentando aprender `C#` vendo códigos de projetos prontos, mas não entendi direito ainda a ordem correta de criação e a dependência deles entre si.

Gostaria de saber como funciona essa engrenagem. Percebo que se esquecer uma peça ela não funcionará, por isso gostaria de saber para que serve cada uma dessas camadas.

Alguém poderia me dar uma breve explicação?

Comment: DAL é um conceito abstrato livre de linguágem: Database Abstraction Layer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Vou tentar ajudar (espero não causar mais fragmentação - cada resposta aqui está dizendo coisas sutilmente diferentes).

Resumo: A pergunta parece se referir à arquitetura MVC: fala de Controller, Model e View. Apresenta o DAL e Negócio como camadas distintas e no mesmo nível que as primeiras 3 (o que é um pouco equivocado, mas mais sobre isso abaixo). Posto isto, vou tentar explicar o que é, afinal de contas, MVC, e como essas 3 camadas se relacionam.

Em primeiro lugar, vou utilizar os termos *Modelo*, *Controlador* e *Visão* (afinal, estamos no SO em português).

Em segundo lugar, MVC não é um termo restrito a .NET, muito menos a C#: é na verdade um padrão arquitetural que existe há *décadas*, que já era utilizado muito antes da popularização da Web (ele foi criado nos anos 1970 pelo pessoal de Smalltalk)! Por outro lado, a *framework* ASP.NET MVC segue a *arquitetura* MVC (então o que vale para esta última vale, em geral, também para a primeira).

Em terceiro, creio que é importante começar definindo a camada que é, de longe, a mais controversa: o *Modelo*.

Traduzindo o que está na entrada [Model-view-controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) da Wikipédia em Inglês, a gente encontra a seguinte frase:

> O componente central, o modelo, consiste em dados de aplicação, **regras de negócio**, lógica e funções.

O fato do termo "modelo" ser usado indiscriminadamente, significando ora um [Active-Record](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record) (por exemplo, pela comunidade Ruby on Rails), ora a [DAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer) ou um mero [DTO](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTO) (pela própria comunidade ASP.NET MVC) não ajuda.

Então vamos parar de bagunça: *Modelo* não só é o nome de uma **camada inteira** (e não o nome de um tipo de classe, ou de um design-pattern específico), como também costuma ser, quase sempre, a **maior** camada de qualquer sistema MVC que se preze! Aliás, é justamente por isso que ela normalmente se divide em sub-camadas: acesso a dados, serviços e etc. (contudo, isto não está descrito na arquitetura MVC, mesmo que muitas vezes seja recomendável).

**Edição** Tentando explicar de uma forma um pouco menos "radical": especificamente no mundo ASP.NET MVC, costuma-se dar o apelido de "modelo" (o nome mais adequado para este tipo de classe é "[View Model](http://eduardopires.net.br/2013/08/asp-net-mvc-view-model-pattern-quando-e-como-utilizar/)") para as classes utilizadas para transportar dados entre o controlador e a visão. E aí fica a pergunta: modelo é uma classe ou uma camada? Bom, da mesma forma que "Rio de Janeiro" é um termo que depende de contexto (pode referenciar a cidade ou o estado), "modelo" também. Formalmente falando, este termo referencia a camada inteira, mas ele pode ser, a princípio, utilizado para referenciar qualquer classe pertencente a ela. Ou seja, uma classe de domínio ou uma entidade, mesmo não sendo "view models", são também "modelos".

E agora vamos definir as outras camadas MVC:

- O *Controlador* é a camada responsável pelas regras *de apresentação*, e por transformar dados entre o *Modelo* e a *Visão*. E muita atenção: regras de apresentação != regras de negócio!
- A *Visão* é a camada responsável por apresentar os dados ao usuário final (ela ainda pode se dividir entre *passiva* e *ativa*, mas isso foge ao escopo desta resposta).

As principais vantagens da arquitetura MVC são, ao meu ver, o *desacoplamento* entre as necessidades de apresentação e regras de negócio, a facilidade no uso de técnicas de TDD e a praticidade em se introduzir novas representações dos mesmos dados (os três conceitos, aliás, estão intimamente relacionados).

Na prática, alguns exemplos das vantagens de se utilizar MVC:

- É possível criar várias Visões diferentes, representando a mesma fonte de dados (por exemplo, apresentar dados na forma de uma listagem detalhada, ou na forma de um gráfico, ou meramente como um pacote JSON - em ASP.NET MVC seria necessário criar uma nova ação no Controlador para cada uma dessas alternativas, mas outras bibliotecas MVC podem permitir isso apenas se adicionando uma nova Visão).
- As regras de negócio se tornam *independente* das necessidades de apresentação - poderiam até ser mantidas por uma equipe a parte. Se ocorrerem alterações em algum objeto de negócio (por exemplo, o nome e o tipo de um campo de um DTO retornado), o impacto é minimizado: a princípio apenas o Controlador (que transforma os dados para o consumo das Visões) precisaria ser alterado.
- Passa a ser possível testar cada camada de forma independente: eu posso conectar as minhas Visões em Controladores de teste (que não consultam a base de dados e utilizam dados *fake*, por exemplo) para verificar se a apresentação está adequada; posso também chamar diretamente os métodos de um Controlador a partir de uma suíte de testes unitários, sem renderizar nenhuma Visão, e por aí vai.

**Edição**

O OP também se refere a duas outras camadas, DAL e Negócio, que *não* são descritas pela arquitetura MVC, mas que precisam ser explicadas também:

- DAL: Data Access Layer, ou Camada de Acesso a Dados. Tipicamente são representadas na forma de classes que encapsulam consultas SQL, ou chamadas a alguma biblioteca ORM (como Entity Framework, NHibernate e Linq to SQL, no caso de .NET).
- [Camada de] Negócio: Classes de serviço, que expõe os dados obtidos a partir da DAL para as camadas superiores, normalmente na forma de DTOs.

Como já disse acima, do ponto de vista da arquitetura MVC elas são "sub-camadas", pertencentes ao Modelo (mas isto não faz com que sejam menos importantes, pelo contrário).

Observação: Quando **ambas** as camadas Negócio e DAL estão presentes (e apenas neste caso), a primeira normalmente funciona como um *gateway* para a segunda. Em outras palavras, a camada DAL é acessada apenas pela Camada de Negócio.

Nem sempre eu sou obrigado a ter essas duas camadas:

- Em aplicações MVC para simples CRUD, aonde só se quer consultar, inserir, editar e excluir dados, não faz sentido ter uma Camada de Negócio. Para estes  casos, Modelo = DAL (e é daí, imagino, que vem o tão comum erro conceitual que me referi acima).
- Em aplicações MVC sem persistência, não faz sentido ter um DAL. Neste outro caso, Modelo = Camada de Negócio (um exemplo típico deste tipo de aplicação é uma calculadora - a Camada de Negócio seria representada pelas variáveis e funções necessárias para efetuar os cálculos).

Mesmo nestes casos "atípicos", a arquitetura ainda é MVC.

E é isso aí! Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Parabens pela resposta amigo. Muito didatica e esclarecedora. Me ajudou muito e ajudará outras pessoas com certeza. +1 e Melhor Resposta. Obrigado.

Comment: Aliás o que é TDD?

Comment: TDD - *Test Driven Development*, ou [Desenvolvimento Orientado a Testes](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_Driven_Development). Um estilo sobre o qual se fala muito, mas não se usa tanto. :) Ainda assim, é algo muito importante de se saber: aprender a usar TDD te faz um programador melhor, na minha opinião (mesmo que, por culpa do empregador, muitas vezes a gente não possa utilizá-lo, mas isso tem melhorado).

Comment: A única coisa que não concordo é colocar regras de negócio, que não são relacionadas ao modelo, dentro desta camada, mas de resto, na minha opinião, sua resposta está perfeita.

Comment: @BetaSystems-RodrigoDuarte: sem querer me repetir e já me repetindo, o que eu fiz foi descrever o que é a arquitetura MVC. **É assim que ela é**. Você pode, por exemplo, achar que é necessário ter uma camada de negócios separada da camada de acesso a dados, e eu concordo!! Mas isso não é descrito pelo MVC. E, na prática, também não foge dele: o Modelo deve ser visto como uma "super-camada" que *contém* as sub-camadas de acesso a dados e de regra de negócio, perfeitamente separadas conforme é o costume hoje em dia.

Comment: @BetaSystems-RodrigoDuarte fiz uma edição na minha resposta, inspirado pelo teu comentário. Sei que não concorda com a forma que eu descrevi o Modelo, mas espero que eu consiga ser mais convincente agora! :)

Comment: @rsenna, ficou muito melhor a explicação, mas ainda adicionaria que na camada de negócios, ficariam todas as regras de negócios pertecentes a aplicação, e na camada de modelo, Model , ficariam as respectivas pertencentes as models em si, como validações e afins... Sobre a sua primeira resposta, ela é mais teorica que prática, sendo assim, eu concordo com você... Demorei a entender isto. :)

Comment: Muito boa a resposta, é interessante também definir bem o que são as regras de Negócios (responsabilidade do Model + DAL) e o que são as regras da camada View (responsabilidade do Controller).

Answer (score 9):

Partindo princípio que você está falando de C# para Web e *ASP.NET MVC*, a forma de se entender as camadas do sistema seriam:

- *View*: Contém a visualização / interface
- *Controller*: Controle de aplicação e lógica ne negócios (pode ser chamada de Negocio, no seu exemplo)
- *Model*: Acesso aos dados (pode ser chamada de DAL (*Data Acccess Layer*), no seu exemplo)

Essas camadas podem ser vistas na ordem que eu exemplifiquei, sendo a parte superior mais próxima do usuário e a parte inferior mais próxima do sistema/máquina.

[image: Modelo de camadas ASP.NET MVC]

As informaões devem sempre correr de baixo pra cima e as requisições/ações de cima para baixo. Além disso as camadas não devem depender de uma camada acima dela. Sempre que necessário a dependência é uma camada dependendo da camada logo abaixo dela, sem pular.

Comment: Só para fazer uma comparação. Eu sempre aprendi (em Java/Struts) que Modelo = Business, pois contém a modelagem dos objetos de negócio. Que o controle de fluxo feito pelo Controller não deve incluir fluxo específico do negócio. Que DAL é diferente de modelo pelo motivo já citado. E o modelo pode eventualmente ser exposto na forma de serviços, colocados à disposição do controller. A parte View está igual.

Comment: @Piovezan No [Java/Struts](http://struts.apache.org/development/1.x/userGuide/building_model.html) você tem os `JavaBeans` que são usados para Model os `Business Logic Beans`, os `System State Beans` e os `Action Form Beans`. O modelo não é MVC puro e os beans tem funções mistas se vermos pelo modelo MVc tradicional, por isso existe essa diferença que você falou. Frameworks Java mais recentes, que não o Struts, tem essas funções mais separadas da forma tradicional.

Comment: Uou. Peço desculpas, mas esta resposta não está correta não. Dizer que "Model/DAL: não contém regras de negócio" é, ao meu ver, absurdo: o Model é justamente a camada que deveria conter (entre outras coisas) as regras de negócio! O que você está sugerindo (manter as regras de negócio no Controller) é normalmente chamado de "fat-controller" e é tido, hoje em dia, como um *anti-pattern*.

Comment: Quais são as outras coisas que deveria conter no Model? E se é assim qual o papel do Controller?

Comment: Não dá para responder na forma de comentários. :) Vou adicionar uma resposta aqui, aguarde um instante.

Comment: Dá uma olhada nisso aqui: http://joncairns.com/2013/04/fat-model-skinny-controller-is-a-load-of-rubbish/ http://stackoverflow.com/a/14045514/412426

Comment: Se for como você está falando é melhor não usar MVC e usar um modelo de 4 camadas onde uma delas é quem tem Business. Model é persistência e ponto final. Por questões de interoperabilidade e portabilidade não devem ter mais nada além de código de persistência e aglomeração de dados.

Comment: @AlexandreMarcondes: não, não é "ponto final". Entendo que você pense assim (é um erro bastante comum) mas essa visão não corresponde a definição formal de Model-view-controller. MVC existe há décadas, não é um fenômeno da Web. Quem desenvolve em Objective-C para OSX, por exemplo, provavelmente utiliza MVC para aplicações desktop.

Comment: @AlexandreMarcondes: (e o link que você passou na verdade **concorda** com o que eu estou dizendo - "Domain Objects" são classes de negócio).

Comment: @AlexandreMarcondes: Opa, só agora notei que você enviou dois links. O que eu disse vale para o [segundo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14045514/412426). O [primeiro](http://joncairns.com/2013/04/fat-model-skinny-controller-is-a-load-of-rubbish), na verdade, é só mais um programador Ruby achando que MVC foi inventado com o Ruby on Rails. :P Ele comete um erro comum nessa comunidade: achar que o Model é o mesmo que "Active Record". Os comentários do Albert, de 15/04/2013, e do Marnen Laibow-Koser, de 30/06/2013, traduzem bem o que estou tentando dizer.

Answer (score 6):

Sua aplicação deve resolver um problema de negócio.
Seguindo esse pensamento o desenvolvimento deve começar pela camada de Negócio.

Dadas as opções citadas, com a camada de Negócio pronta, você poderia partir para sua camada de apresentação (Asp.Net MVC):

1. Crie o Controller (interpreta as ações do usuário e as mapeia para chamadas do Model).
2. Crie o Model (representa os dados da aplicação que serão exibidos na View).
3. Crie a View (interface do usuário e em geral é criada a partir do Model).

Durante o desenvolvimento da camada de apresentação (Asp.Net MVC), você vai precisar recuperar/gravar dados, então, a medida que você precisar de métodos que irão recuperar/gravar dados você vai desenvolvendo o DAL.

Em suma, você pode iniciar o desenvolvimento pela camada de Negócio, obedecendo a seguinte sequência:

Negocio > Camada de Apresentação (Controller > Model > View) em paralelo a sua camada de Infraestrutura (DAL).

Answer (score 3):

Sua pergunta é muito ampla para uma simples resposta aqui, mas o ideal seria:

`Modelo -> Dados -> Negócios -> Controller`

Se houver necessidade de distribuir, uma camada deste tipo:

`Modelo-> Dados -> Negócios -> API/Serviço -> Controller`

Tente abstrair em interfaces para não gerar dependências dos tipos concretos, por exemplo, na camada de `Negócios`, trabalhe com interfaces da camada de `Dados` e no `Controller` com interfaces da camada de `Negócios`. Isto facilitará a troca de componentes no futuro caso seja necessário.

Existe um projeto chamado [Sharp Architecture](http://sharparchitecture.net/), que dispõe de uma arquitetura de exemplo  entre camadas e injeção de dependência, boas práticas no desenvolvimento de software, vale a pena dar uma olhada.