# Como funciona a comunicação entre as camadas em MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Comecei a estudar MVC, mas ainda estou na teoria e me veio na cabeça a dúvida de como funciona na prática a conversação entre as camadas. Alguém poderia dar um exemplo de código em C# sem utilização do framework MVC?

Obs: Antes de sugerirem, já vi as respostas de uma pergunta parecida ([Como funciona a interação entre as camadas em C# e qual a função de cada uma?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/223/como-funciona-a-interacao-entre-as-camadas-em-c-e-qual-a-funcao-de-cada-uma)) e ainda continuo com essa minha dúvida. Gostaria de exemplos, de código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A camada VIEW invoca o **Click** do botão.
2. O click do botão irá chamar a camada de negócios **BLL**.
3. A BLL se encarrega de fazer as regras de negócio e invoca a camada
   **DAL** para fazer a interação com o banco de dados.

> Exemplo, **CAMADA VIEW:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNome" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>    
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>    
<asp:Button ID="btnSalvar" runat="server" Text="Salvar" OnClick="btnSalvar_Click" />    


<%    
    void btnSalvar_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)    
    {    
        //Envia os dados do formulário    
        //para a camada de lógica da aplicação(BLL)    
        Bll.Usuario bllUsuario = new Bll.Usuario();    
        bllUsuario.Salvar(txtNome.Text,txtEmail.Text);    
    }    
%>
```

**CAMADA BLL:**

```
namespace Bll
{
    public class Usuario
    {
        public void Salvar(String Nome, String Email)
        {
        //Realiza a lógica com os dados recebidos
        //da camada de apresentação, e envia para
        //a camada de acesso a dados (DAL)
            if (Nome != "" && Email != "")
            {
                Dal.Usuario dalUsuario = new Dal.Usuario();

                dalUsuario.Salvar(Nome, Email);
            }
        }
    }
```

**CAMADA DAL:**

```
namespace Dal
{
    public class Usuario
    {
        public void Salvar(String Nome, String Email)
        {
        //Recebe os dados recebidos da camada de lógica (BLL)
        //e salva os dados no banco de dados (back-end)
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SalvarUsuario", conexao);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome", Nome);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
}
```

> FONTE:
>   http://imasters.com.br/desenvolvimento/visual_studio/aplicacao-em-3-camadas-com-asp-net-c/

Comment: Tem certeza que isso é MVC. Não é o MVC que eu conheço. O artigo que você citou diz o contrário. Você está utilizando WebForms. Apesar de ser **possível** modelá-lo como MVC (dá trabalho, não compensa, desconheço alguém que tenha feito) não é ele que é usado para MVC.

Comment: Eu dei esse exemplo pois creio que a dúvida do @Caique C. era como fica o código de conversação entre as camadas, veja esse trecho da pergunta "Alguém poderia dar um exemplo de código em C# sem utilização do framework MVC?".

Comment: Entendi, as perguntas do título e interna são discrepantes.

Answer (score 0):

O Mvc é composto de 3 camadas Model View e Controller, no asp .net mvc temos o seguinte fluxo:

web o navegador chama uma action como por exemplo seudominio/Controller/action ou para exemplificar melhor localhost/home/index como mostra o código abaixo:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Pode notar que a primeira coisa que ele chama é a controller/Action que por sua vez funciona como um gerente, fazendo um passo a passo até chegar na view, no código abaixo temos uma implementação onde a controller tem que buscar dados, dai neste caso ela terá que acessar a model.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var person = new PersonRepositoty();
        var model = person.PersonRep.Get();

        return View(model);
    }
```

Que logo em seguida passa para a view, que esta em View/Home/index.

Logo ao meu modo de ver a controller é um gerente que pode consultar uma model para buscar dados e por fim passar para uma view que ira apresentar na tela de um usuario.

Obs.: Toda ActionResult tem uma view.

Comment: Tecnicamente a ActionResult pode ser diversas coisas além de uma View. Pode ser um JSON, um Stream, uma imagem etc

Comment: Opa perfeito o seu comentário...